# Firebase Clients App

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was making an app for one of my family members so that they could better manage their clients but ran into some issues. This is my first time using Firebase and I just can't seem to get my code to work! The part in which I am getting stuck involves Firebase's Realtime Database, and I am working in XCode 8.3 with Swift 3.1.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

    var specClientId = ""

    class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var nameCell: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet var statusCell: UILabel!

    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

        var tableArray: [String] = []

        var clientId: [String] = []

        var statusArray:[String] = []

        @IBAction func signOut(_ sender: Any) {

            UserDefaults.resetStandardUserDefaults()

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueBackLogin", sender: self)

        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return tableArray.count

        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellFront") as! MyCell

            cell.nameCell.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.statusCell.text = statusArray[indexPath.row]

            return cell

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            specClientId = clientId[indexPath.row]

            ref.child("Users").child(specClientId).child("lastUpdate").removeValue()

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            if FIRApp.defaultApp() == nil {
                FIRApp.configure()
            }

            ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            ref.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                let specificValues = value?.allKeys

                self.tableArray.removeAll()

                self.statusArray.removeAll()

                self.clientId.removeAll()

                var it = 0

                for Uservalue in specificValues! {

                    self.tableArray.append("")

                    self.statusArray.append("")

                    self.clientId.append(Uservalue as! String)

                    self.ref.child("Users")
                        .child(Uservalue as! String)
                        .child("name")
                        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                            let nameValue = snapshot.value as? String

                            self.tableArray.insert(nameValue!, at: it)

                            self.tableArray = self.tableArray.filter {$0 != ""}

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }) { (error) in

                            print(error.localizedDescription)

                        }

                    self.ref.child("Users")
                        .child(Uservalue as! String)
                        .child("lastUpdate")
                        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                            if let nameValue = snapshot.value as? String {

                                self.statusArray.insert("*", at: it)

                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            } else {

                                self.statusArray.insert("", at: it)

                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }

                        }) { (error) in

                            print(error.localizedDescription)

                    }

                    it += 1

                }

            }) { (error) in

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

My main issue is that when I get the user's name and their lastUpdate status, the array lists do not match up correctly and the TableView displays the wrong information in terms of which User has submitted their updates. To fix this issue, I tried to use the insert method in my arrays but now the app crashes. Previously, I was using the append method but that leads to the wrong information being displayed in the TableView. I would appreciate it if any of you could help me with this issue.

Note: The App Crashes due to the StatusArray not having the same amount of elements as the TableArray. This is caused by the TableArray having some empty elements with no names in them.

Thanks,
KPS

Edit 1:

```
for Uservalue in specificValues! {

                self.clientId.append(Uservalue as! String)

                let user = User()

                self.ref.child("Users")
                    .child(Uservalue as! String)
                    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let nameValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                        let specNameValue = nameValue?.allKeys

                        var i = 0

                        while i < specNameValue!.count {

                            if specNameValue?[i] as? String == "name" {

                                user.name = nameValue?.allValues[i] as! String

                            } else if specNameValue?[i] as? String == "lastUpdate" {

                                user.status = "*"

                            } else if specNameValue?[i] as? String != "name" && specNameValue?[i] as? String != "lastUpdate" && specNameValue?[i] as? String != "message" && specNameValue?[i] as? String != "adminMessage" && specNameValue?[i] as? String != "photoURL" {

                                user.status = ""

                            }

                            i += 1

                        }


                    }) { (error) in

                        print(error.localizedDescription)

                    }

                self.tableArray.append(user)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason your app is crashing is because in your cell for row you are reloading after loading the first user and the cell expects the statusArray to have elements already.

```
cell.nameCell.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
cell.statusCell.text = statusArray[indexPath.row] // fails here I assume
```

There a few issues going on here that I'll try to address.

- You are reloading the table immediately for each child that is iterated through. It would be smart to append elements to each array then once completed display all elements by calling `tableView.reloadData()`
- Are status' independent of the name that you are expecting? If the data is correlated, it would be smart to create a simple Object to house this data and have a single array of data that the tableView will use for it's dataSource
- Once your data is fully loaded, you could sort the data accordingly then reload the datasource to solve the issue of pulling data from the server that is out of order. This is why the `append(element: )` is simple and useful

Hopefully this helps! It may seem like a bit more work but it would definitely be beneficial to performance, organization and readability for yourself.

Comment: Hi, I tried to reload the data after appending all of the elements but the data never reloads. Also, I think the Object Idea is really good but how would I go about doing that for the TableView? I am pretty new to iOS development and if this were android, I would have already had it done. Thanks

Comment: Oh, so would I create an Array of Objects and then append to that Array with an object containing both the array and the status of the user? Thanks

Comment: @kps2501 Correct. Something along those lines. If the data is correlated, then yes that would make things a bit simpler for you. That way you only need to access the object at the index in your array to populate the cell!

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try this and let you know if it works or if I have any other issues. Thanks!

Comment: @kps2501 Awesome, if you wouldn't mind selecting this as your given answer I would appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried the code but my TableView never reloads the Data. Where do you suggest I put my append and reloadData() statements?

Comment: So, when you make your request, you should wait until you receive a success or fail. On success you will need to parse the snapshot values into your new temp object, then append that object to the dataSource. Once each your users has been parsed and added. You should then reload the tableview.

Make sure you print out debug statements throughout your code to see when data is being populated and that everything is happening as you would expect!

Comment: Hi, I got the whole thing working! Thanks so much for the help! I was also having some problems with a Javascript Script that I wrote for Firebase Cloud Messaging. Can you by any chance help me with that? Thanks